# Read pandas dataframe from file until sentinel value?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the CSV file below that stores multiple dataframes, can I use `pd.read_csv()` to read until a sentinel value is detected, in this case "#"?

```
x,y
2,4
3,9
#
x,y
2,8
3,27
```

Comment: I would just read the file as text and parse into separate dataframes when I reach the sentinel value

Comment: eventually, do you need to read **until** (into 1 df) OR split the file on 2 dfs?

Comment: There isn't any elegant way to do this directly with `read_csv()`. The closest you could get using functionality baked into that method would only be if you already knew which row this sentinel value landed in where you could use `skiprows` with a lambda like `lambda x: x<*the row in which the sentinel value appears*` but.. at that point you might as well just read the whole thing into a DF and split it after it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read **until** the first comment, you can try:

```
from itertools import takewhile
import io

with open('data.csv') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(list(takewhile(lambda x: not x.strip().startswith('#'), f)))))
```

Or:

```
import re, io

with open('data.csv') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(next(re.finditer('[^#]+', f.read()), '').group()))
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  2  4
1  3  9
```

To read **all** DataFrames:

```
import io

dfs = []
with open('data.csv') as f:
    for chunk in f.read().split('#\n'):
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(chunk)))

dfs[1]

   x   y
0  2   8
1  3  27
```